# PublishSubject's .onNext not being seen downstream

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a method which looks a bit like the following:

```
fun start(id: Long?): Observable<Result> {                   
    return load(id)                                                   
            .flatMap { optional ->                                                        
               return@flatMap Observable.just(Result)                                                                          
            }                                                                             

            .mergeWith(subject)                                                       
}
```

where `subject` is a `PublishSubject`. Later on, `subject.onNext` is called. However, this emission is not seen downstream.

As far as I'm aware, `.mergeWith` will not complete until both streams complete. `Observable.just` immediately invokes `.onNext` and then `onComplete`, and this can be observed if `.doOnNext()` and `.doOnComplete()` statements are placed before `.mergeWith()`. However, a `.doOnComplete()` statement placed *after* `.mergeWith` is not called.

Why is the `PublishSubject`'s `.onNext()` not being observed downstream?

Comment: Please provide more information. What does the load method do? Did you mean to write `return@flatMap Observable.just(optional)`? What purpose has this `flatMap` here at all? I wrote a Test and the data of my subject got emitted.

Comment: Is the `Observable` returned by `start` subscribed to when `subject.onNext` is called?